# How to convert a future's output?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

With Tokio's futures, if you want to convert an `Error` in the causal chain of combinators, you use `from_err::<NewType>()`. I want the same functionality, but instead for the `Item` in `impl Future<Item = (), Error = ()>`.

An example of some of my code:

```rust
let mut async_series_client = vec![];
async_series_client.push(Box::new(
    SocketHandler::connect(
        port,
        addr,
        handle,
        tx_wave,
        tx_linear,
        KcpSessionManager::new(&handle2).unwrap(),
    )
    .from_err::<HyxeError>()
    .join(tube)
    .map_err(|mut err| err.printf()),
));
```

This returns `((),())` (Side question: does it return a tuple of () because of the join?). I want it to return just `()`. How can I do this?

Comment: Yes it is because of join, just add mapping to the join combinator, like you did when adding map_err

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Future::map`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.23/futures/future/trait.Future.html#method.map). This is a parallel to `Option::map`, `Result::map`, and `Iterator::map`:

```
use futures::{future, Future}; // 0.1.27

fn some_future() -> impl Future<Item = i32, Error = ()> {
    future::ok(42)
}

fn change_item() -> impl Future<Item = String, Error = ()> {
    some_future().map(|i| i.to_string())
}
```

See also [`Stream::map`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.23/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.map).

---

When `async`/`await` syntax is stabilized, you *may* never need to use this combinator again as you can just use normal methods:

```
async fn some_future() -> i32 {
    42
}

async fn change_output() -> String {
    some_future().await.to_string()
}
```

Or `Result::map`:

```
async fn some_future() -> Result<i32, ()> {
    Ok(42)
}

async fn change_output() -> Result<String, ()> {
    some_future().await.map(|i| i.to_string())
}
```

But it still exists:

```
use futures::{Future, FutureExt}; // 0.3.0-alpha.16

async fn some_future() -> i32 {
    42
}

fn change_output() -> impl Future<Output = String> {
    some_future().map(|i| i.to_string())
}
```

Comment: Thanks again, Shep. I really like the old version, because it provides a more intuitive way of thinking (i.e., through lambda calculus). I think that abstracting away the lower-levels makes thinking about what's happening harder and less flexible to do and understand (for me, at least).